# Passar parâmetro dinamicamente para plug-in Jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, plugin

Tenho um código javascript/jquery que salva uma nova no meu sistema, nesse código quero que quando a requisição falhar seja executado um plug-in de notificação, queria passar para esse plug-in os dados de `jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown` do método `.fail()` sem ter que colocar no escopo do plug-in assim `$('.wrapper').notify(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);`

```
$(function(){

   $.ajaxSetup({
        type: "post",
        dataType: "json",
      beforeSend: function(){
         $.loader('show');
      },
      complete: function(){
         $.loader('hide');
      }
   });

   $('.js-anotacao').on('click',function(e){
      
      e.preventDefault();
      
      var selct = $(this);
      var forms = selct.closest('form');
      var dados = forms.serialize();

      $.ajax({
         data: dados,
         url: $.path() + "api/RegisterLog.php",
         success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
         }
      }).fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
         $('.wrapper').notify();
      });

   });

});
```

Esse é código inicial do plug-in:

```
(function ($) {

   // valores padrões da aplicação
   var _defaults = {
      background : "green",
      type       : "success",
      color      : "white"
   }

   // executa o código quando houver seletor
   $.fn.notify = function(options) {
      
      var settings  = $.extend(true, {}, _defaults, options); 
      var container = $(this);

      if (jqXHR) {
         // faz alguma coisa
      }
      
      console.log(jqXHR);

   }

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Qual o problema que está a encontrar? O codigo quando corre e falha não entra no fail()?

Comment: Não, não é esse o problema. Estou fazem um plug-in para notificações e query passar para eles os valores de `jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown` sem precisar colocar assim `$('.wrapper').notify(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);`